# Why the layer is empty

Tags: qgis

I closed a side panel I had, where I had a list of layers and which I used to switch on and off layers, and I cannot find how to get it back. "View > Panels" and tick "Layers"； then the Layers panel is back, but why is it empty?

[image]

Comment: Cant you just add the layers again?

Comment: Reload you project, if you saved it.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of the browser panel that let you add layers from all kind of different sources....

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the screenshot, it seems your project has no layers, so either you unadvertetnly closed the project, or QGIS crashed (the yellow alert pointing in that direction) and you didn't notice.
In any case, as @BERA suggests, try loading the layers again, and take not of what happens next. If QGIS crashes you might need to fix it, possibly performing a new installation.